# Load some private var on switch condition

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a simple iOS game, and I have some problems. 
Indeed, I created my different classes for my elements : planet, bullet, background, and asteroids.
However when I try to initialize them on switch condition (from the GameScene), I have the error message "expected declaration".

The variable "lvlSelected", is global and represents the level asked by the player (from an other scene).

Here's my switch code :

```
 switch lvlSelected {
case 1 :
private var planet = Planet(imageName: "Planet1")
private var bullet = Bullet(imageName: "Bullet1")
private var background = Background(imageName: "Background1")
private var asteroide = Asteroides(img: "Asteroid1")

case 2 :
private var planet = Planet(imageName: "Planet2")
private var bullet = Bullet(imageName: "Bullet2")
private var background = Background(imageName: "Background2")
private var asteroide = Asteroides(img: "Asteroid2")

default :
private var planet = Planet(imageName: "Planet")
private var bullet = Bullet (imageName: "Bullet")
private var background = Background(imageName : "Background")
private var asteroide = Asteroides(img."Asteroid")
}
```

Thanks for your help

---

Here's my Planet's class :

```
class Planet:SKSpriteNode {

init(imageName: String){

    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed : imageName)
    super.init(texture: texture, color: .clear, size: texture.size())

    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width/2, center: self.anchorPoint) 
    self.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false 
    self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = GameScene.physicsCategories.planet
    self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = GameScene.physicsCategories.none
    self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = GameScene.physicsCategories.asteroid

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
 func addPlanet(parent: GameScene) {
    self.setScale(0.55)
    self.position = CGPoint(x: parent.size.width / 2, y: -self.size.height)
    self.zPosition = 2
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    parent.addChild(self)
}
```

Comment: 1. You can't use `private` with local variables. 2. You probably don't want local variables.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the way you want.

```
private var planet = Planet(imageName: "Planet")
private var bullet = Bullet (imageName: "Bullet")
private var background = Background(imageName : "Background")
private var asteroide = Asteroides(img."Asteroid")

switch lvlSelected {
case 1 :
  planet = Planet(imageName: "Planet1")
  bullet = Bullet(imageName: "Bullet1")
  background = Background(imageName: "Background1")
  asteroide = Asteroides(img: "Asteroid1")
break
case 2 :
  planet = Planet(imageName: "Planet2")
  bullet = Bullet(imageName: "Bullet2")
  background = Background(imageName: "Background2")
  asteroide = Asteroides(img: "Asteroid2")
  break
default :
  break
}
```

If you declare a var inside a switch case will be available inside that case only.

Comment: rmaddy because you already have defined your defaults when you declared them.

Comment: That's my point though. There is no need to initialize them just to reset them in the switch.

Comment: I see your point, would you work with optionals instead in this case?

Comment: Depends on where they are declared. If they are class properties then maybe make them implicitly unwrapped. If they are local to the function containing the switch then make them normal `let` constants with no initial value.

Comment: Yeah my solution was like this to simplify :-)

Comment: @LucasA. This answer is their solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a switch in your case,  you can use string interpolation:

```
class GameScene : SKScene
{
    private let planet : Planet
    private let bullet : Bullet
    private let background : Background
    private let asteroide : Asteroides
    convenience init(lvlSelected : Int){

        let level = 1 ... 2 ~= lvlSelected ? "\(lvlSelected)" : ""
        planet = Planet(imageName: "Planet\(level)")
        bullet = Bullet (imageName: "Bullet\(level)")
        background = Background(imageName: "Background\(level)")
        asteroid = Asteroides(img: "Asteroid\(level)")
        self.init() //whatever init you use here
    }
}
```

`~=` is the pattern match operator, and `#a ... #b` means range of numbers between a and b including a and b, so you are asking if a number is in a certain range

`(condition) ? (statement 1) : (statement 2)` is the ternary operator which is if  condition true then statement 1 else statement 2

`"\(var)"` is string interpolation that tells the string to inject the value of var into the string